# RPI4B Ubnutu Server 20.10 wifi setup

Tags: networking, wifi, pi-4, ubuntu, wpa-supplicant

I recently installed Ubuntu Server 20.10 on my RPI 4B and cannot get wifi to work. I followed the instructions [here](https://itsfoss.com/connect-wifi-terminal-ubuntu/), [here](https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-20-04-connect-to-wifi-from-command-line), and [here](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/connect-to-wi-fi-from-terminal-on-ubuntu-18-04-19-04-with-wpa-supplicant).

When I attempt to setup wifi via wpa_supplicant (the last link) with the command:

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -i wlan0
```

I get the following:

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
wlan0: Failed to initiate sched scan
wlan0: Failed to initiate sched scan
wlan0: Failed to initiate sched scan
wlan0: Failed to initiate sched scan
wlan0: Failed to initiate sched scan
wlan0: Failed to initiate sched scan
wlan0: Failed to initiate sched scan
wlan0: Failed to initiate sched scan
wlan0: Failed to initiate sched scan
wlan0: Failed to initiate sched scan
wlan0: Failed to initiate sched scan
```

Upon checking the /etc/wpa_supplicant file I found that there is no wpa_supplicant.conf file and I cannot find instructions for creating one from scratch, or an example file. I think this is why I can't connect via wifi with my pi.

For setting up via netplan:

50-cloud-init.yaml file:

```
# This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
# to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
# network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
    version: 2
    wifis:
        wlan0:
            access-points:
                "XXXXXXXXX":
                    password: "XXXXXXXX"
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
```

If it isn't the wpa_supplicant.conf file, I am out of ideas. It may be worth noting that I am trying to set this up with the ethernet cord attached because I am doing all this over ssh.

I tried the method shared by @tttapa in the comments I get the following output when I run `sudo netplan --debug generate`:

`DEBUG:command generate: running ['/lib/netplan/generate']
** (generate:5090): DEBUG: 15:18:36.438: Processing input file /etc/netplan/10-my-config.yaml..

** (generate:5090): DEBUG: 15:18:36.439: starting new processing pass

** (generate:5090): DEBUG: 15:18:36.439: wlan0: adding wifi AP 'XXXXX'

** (generate:5090): DEBUG: 15:18:36.439: Processing input file /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml..

** (generate:5090): DEBUG: 15:18:36.439: starting new processing pass

** (generate:5090): DEBUG: 15:18:36.439: wlan0: adding wifi AP ''

** (generate:5090): DEBUG: 15:18:36.439: We have some netdefs, pass them through a final round of validation

** (generate:5090): DEBUG: 15:18:36.439: wlan0: setting default backend to 1

** (generate:5090): DEBUG: 15:18:36.439: Configuration is valid

** (generate:5090): DEBUG: 15:18:36.439: eth0: setting default backend to 1

** (generate:5090): DEBUG: 15:18:36.439: Configuration is valid

** (generate:5090): DEBUG: 15:18:36.440: Generating output files..

** (generate:5090): DEBUG: 15:18:36.440: openvswitch: definition eth0 is not for us (backend 1)

** (generate:5090): DEBUG: 15:18:36.440: NetworkManager: definition eth0 is not for us (backend 1)

** (generate:5090): DEBUG: 15:18:36.440: Creating wpa_supplicant config

** (generate:5090): DEBUG: 15:18:36.440: wlan0: Creating wpa_supplicant
configuration file run/netplan/wpa-wlan0.conf

ERROR: : ASCII passphrase must be between 8 and 63 characters (inclusive)`

It seems netplan is checking the 50-cloud-init.yaml, despite running the command `sudo bash -c "echo 'network: {config: disabled}' > /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg"` before executing the generate command and rebooting.

Comment: What happened when you tried the netplan generate / apply commands?

Comment: https://tttapa.github.io/Pages/Raspberry-Pi/Installation+Setup/WiFi-Setup.html#disabling-cloud-init

Comment: Ubuntu server uses systemd-networkd and AFAIK does not use wpa-supplicant. Just use Raspberry Pi OS (which is well documented and works).

Comment: Note `wlp4s0` is a meaningless device on the Pi. You presumably copied without understanding *Predictable Network Interface Names*

Comment: The net plan generate and apply commands execute as expected. I have already tried all instructions that pertain to netplan. They don't work. I dont want to use RpiOS I want to make this work. I'm not using wlp4s0 im using wlan0.

Comment: Your post leads me to believe you didn't follow those instructions carefully enough, since you're editing the cloud-init config file, which even explicitly states that changes will not persist. Please see the link I posted earlier: you have to disable cloud-init first, and then create your own Netplan config file. If that still doesn't work, you can use Netplan's `--debug` flag to find out what goes wrong.

Comment: @tttapa please see edit.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I am having the same issue. I have tried about everything I can find on the internet to solve this but cannot find the solution. It is like wlan0 is permanently down.

Comment: See my latest answer, I think it's the key

Answer (score 3):

I was able to resolve this issue by adding my region to the `/etc/default/crda` file.

```
# Set REGDOMAIN to a ISO/IEC 3166-1 alpha2 country code so that iw(8) may set
# the initial regulatory domain setting for IEEE 802.11 devices which operate
# on this system.
#
# Governments assert the right to regulate usage of radio spectrum within
# their respective territories so make sure you select a ISO/IEC 3166-1 alpha2
# country code suitable for your location or you may infringe on local
# legislature. See `/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' for a table of timezone
# descriptions containing ISO/IEC 3166-1 alpha2 country codes.

REGDOMAIN=
```

After adding your region to the REGDOMAIN and rebooting, if you are using the latest binary blobs for the wifi you should be good to go.

Comment: I've followed same steps as OP (even documented steps in official page), but this was the solution. Just a guess: maybe wpa_supplicant fail in the scan because country isn't defined, so, it do not know what country rules to apply.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked, posted it here just in case someone struggled as much as myself

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on a Raspberry Pi 4 with Ubuntu Server 22.04, but modifying `/etc/default/crda` had no effect.

The solution was to create a file `/etc/modprobe.d/cfg80211.conf` with the following content (modify the `US` value with your country code) :

```
options cfg80211 ieee80211_regdom=US
```

Then reboot the system.

Solution originally found [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/820191).